# Issue with readLine() method

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am building a Chat system, where I need wait to get the User input (Sender) as well as to display the reply message (from receiver) at the same time.

So I am using a while loop for receiving and sending the messages:

```
while((text = inFromUser.readLine()) != null) //Msg from Sender
{
    while((data_from_server=inFromServer.readLine()) != null) //Msg from receiver
    {
        System.out.println("Displaying Output=" + data_from_server);
        System.out.println(data_from_server);
    }
    System.out.println("Getting Input=" + text);
    outToserver.writeBytes(text + "\n");
}
```

My Problem is the client may send inputs again and again ,whereas the receiver may/may not send the reply back. But according to my logic, it's always expecting a input from the receiver and Vice Versa. Please suggest to fix this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to need more than one thread. Think about it - you have to wait until the user enters some data, and when that happens, display it immediately. You also have to wait until the server gives you some data, and display *that* immediately.

You can't wait for both at once; if you did, nothing would be displayed until both the user and the server had entered a line. You can't wait for one, then the other; if you did, the client couldn't read what they wrote until the server sent a message, or vice versa.

You need to wait for both at the same time, *but running side-by-side*. You want to perform an action as soon as either of them return something. This means you need to run a second thread. One thread waits for the user, and one thread waits for the server.

Comment: This answer would be more clear without two contradictory statements: "_You can't wait for both at once;_" but "_You need to wait for both at the same time,_"

Comment: But side-by-side, and that can only be done with two threads.